# Prove that if $p$ and $q$ are positive integers such that $p \mid q$ & $q \mid p$ then $p=q$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

My approach is taking,

$q=pk$ and $p=qm$ (where, $k$ and $m$ are integers).

But I don't understand how to equate them.

Comment: Here's a hint: if p > q, is it possible that p|q ?

Answer (score 0):

As $q=pk$ and $p=qm$, so $q = qmk$, as $p,q \neq 0$, so $mk=1$, now as $m,k \in \mathbb{Z}$ so $m,k \in \{1,-1\}$, so $p=q$ or $p=-q$.

Now in particular if $p,q$ are positive integers then $m,k \in \{1\}$, so $p=q$.